# What is the purpose of having implemented INotifyPropertyChanged on ObservableCollection?

Tags: wpf, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

`ObservableCollection` implements both `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

- I understand that additions,
  deletions (+ clear), and replacement
  of items are notifiable to consumers
  through the **collection**'s event
  `CollectionChanged`, and that updates
  in the existing items can be
  monitored using the **items**' event
  `PropertyChanged` if they implement
  themselves `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
- I read from others that you can't
  register on the collection's event
  `PropertyChanged` because it is
  readonly.

**So what is its purpose, what utilization can we do of it**?

The comments here and there seem to make the discussion confused by implying that the magic of `ObservableCollection` is to implement both interfaces, allowing to be notified both for collection and items content changes, while this is not correct (this is ignored by many examples where the collection is bound to a listbox which updates magically after items content is changed, suggesting the collection notifies the listbox).

Actually it seems the only superiority of the collection is to implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`. Dealing with items property changes seems not at all easier with `ObservableCollection` than with another collection: it is possible only if the items implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, which they may not do, and if the user manages to hook on this event independently of the collection.

**Is this correct?**

Answer (score 9):

If you look at the `ObservableCollection<T>` source code with Reflector, you can see that this event is raised for two properties :

```
this.OnPropertyChanged("Count");
this.OnPropertyChanged("Item[]");
```

Note that `ObservableCollection<T>` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` explicitly, so you can access the `PropertyChanged` event only through a `INotifyPropertyChanged` variable :

```
INotifyPropertyChanged inpc = myObservableCollection;
inpc.PropertyChanged += myEventHandler;
```

Comment: While factually accurate and succinct  I am not sure how that answers the "so whats the purpose?" part of the Q

Comment: The purpose is to notify subscribers that the collection has changed. In that aspect it serves the same purpose as the CollectionChanged event, but INotifyPropertyChanged is more widely supported than INotifyCollectionChanged

Answer (score 3):

WPFs binding mechanism can use INotifyPropertyChanged (INpc) out of the box.

INpc as the name suggests allows WPF to detect changes to object properties that may or may not be part of a collection.

ObservableCollection (OC) implements INotifyCollectionChanged (InCC) where as you say the collection itself notifies WPF ( and anyone else equipped to handle the updates) of updates to its items collection (additions deletions etc). If the OC contains objects that do not themselves implement INpc then WPF has no way of knowing how each items properties have changed.

**Update**

In answering the following question "can we rely on the collection INpc event instead of registering on each new item for being notified ?" the answer is no. If each item does not implement Inpc on its properties then WPF has no way of knowing what values have changed on a per item basis.

WPF will still know from the OC when the items have been added to or deleted in part. The Items property uses the INpc to notify of updates just like any class implementing INpc on its properties. InCC is implemented to track collection changes not values on each item within items.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess: so one can be notified of changes to the collection's Count property?